# Is there any "mocha maven plugin"?

Tags: maven-plugin, mocha.js

I would like to check if there is any plugin that exists for running mocha test cases in maven test phase, and to return BUILD SUCCESS or FAILURE based on test result

-lucky

Answer (score 5):

I was interested in the question too. *I'm testing the nodejs code, so it may be not very relevant.*
No success so far discovering the plugin I need, but if you need only the failing build process you can use **maven-antrun-plugin** like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>test-nodejs</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks name="Run mocha tests">
                    <exec dir="${basedir}"
                          executable="npm"
                          failonerror="true">
                        <arg value="test"/>
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>

            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Pay attention to **failonerror** argument.

One more thing to note (in case of **NodeJS**) - you need to setup the **package.json** file to support `npm test` command, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
  "test" : "mocha -R tap"
},
```

and your tests should reside in **test** folder. Also, mocha treats subfolder well enough, so you can make reasonable test case folder structure.